# PHPWord export includes HTML tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, phpword

I am going to try to explain this as best I can so please bear with me.

I am using **Laravel** and **PHPWord**.

I have a form that gets filled out that stores data, in my form I am using certain **jquery plugins** that makes it look a bit more nice for the user to fill in the form. The plugin I am specifically referring to is **bootstrap-wysihtml5** and it looks great.

**Now I know that the editor is creating the HTML tags and that the data is actually being stored in the DB with the HTML tags.**

Hereafter the user can then download this form in a word document format**(PHPWord)**. It exports everything very nicely as well but my problem comes in when viewing the data the user has filled in.

In the word document you will have data written such as:
`<div>
   <p>This is the data</p>
 </div>`

So basically all I want to do is prevent the HTML tags from being exported and displayed in the word document but I am not too sure on how to achieve this.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated and I am more than willing to supply relevant code that will help solve the question.

Comment: Firstly, i believe the best way to approach this, is to find a way to export data without the HTML tags. Have you searched/tried how to do this? If there is no other way, the first thing it came to my mind is to, create a preg_match function which will remove tags if are found while you write the data to Word doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php.

Comment: As far as I understand PHPWord does not support that.

Comment: @MinaAbadir Can you please share the PHPWord generator code you have written?

Comment: I did not write any, however, in order to create docx with php, you need to write it through adding sections, with different style for different sections.

Comment: I am sorry, I was mistaken. Please check that example: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_26_Html.php

Comment: @Tony... I have looked into it and so far I've had no luck while searching hence why I came here. It seems to me that your method would work best for what I want to achieve. I am going to try it, **thanks**.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, why not try PHP function strip_tags? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @Alesito - Thank you, Tony has suggested that I try that and it seems to be working fine.